# Resource needed on Lerch's transcendent

Tags: reference-request, special-functions

I am looking for resources in english which discuss basic properties of the Lerch's transcendent function.

The Lerch Transcendant is defined by:
$$f(x,\xi,q,p)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(pq)^{n^2}(x\xi)^{-2n}}{(-p\xi^{-2};p^2)_n}$$

The only article I know regarding this is the following:
Lerch, M.: Nová analogie řady theta a některé zvláštní hypergeometrické řady Heineovy. Rozpravy 3, 1–10 (1893)

Comment: there is quite an extensive entry in Wikipedia, with a whole bunch of references; what are you missing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function

Comment: Not sure it is the same as yours, but mathworld has identities:  http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/

Comment: What you have written looks more like a Appell-Lerch sum than a Lerch transcendent (which has been noted is related to the Hurwitz $\zeta$-function, not to a $\Theta$-series).

Comment: @kantelope: I have failed to find any source which defines Appell Lerch sum in the manner described above. Can you suggest something?